# Compiling Visual basic adds cast operations

Tags: vb.net, com, compiler-construction

On compiling a visual basic assembly, int32 variables are cast as int64 for calls to adodb methods that require int32. This results in a method not found exceptions at run time. The unnecessary cast operation can be seen when using reflector to inspect the site of the method call and is not present in the source code.

To further muddy the waters when the code is compiled on my 64bit windows 7 machine all is well, but on a 64bit windows 2008 r2 the unnecessary cast is added.

Does any one know how to stop this happening?

Comment: Just out of curiousity, do you have Option Strict enabled in the project?

Comment: I tried it with option strict on and off. It made no difference.

Comment: Very strange. Option Strict On really shouldn't be adding extra casts to Int64.

Answer (score 0):

Try compiling the app specifically for x86/32bit.

[How do I force MSBuild to compile for 32-bit mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1074654/how-do-i-force-msbuild-to-compile-for-32-bit-mode)

Comment: That does not seem to help. It still puts in the unwanted cast operations.