# Building InstallShield LE project with MSBuild - Error MSB4062

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild, installshield

I work with Visual Studio 2012, and I just switched my deployment tools from NSIS to InstallShield. I've added new projects to my solution for InstallShield installers. When I build in Visual Studio (the IDE) I've no errors, no warnings and I'm happy.

Now, I want to have a script that build the full solution without launching the IDE. But when I run MSBuild in the command line, like that

```
MSBuild MySolution.sln /t:Build /p:Configuration=Release
```

I get following error MSB4062

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\InstallShield\2012SpringLimited\InstallShield.targets(21,3): error MSB4062: The "Microsoft.Build.Tasks.AssignProjectConfiguration" task could not be loaded from the assembly Microsoft.Build.Tasks.v3.5. Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Build.Tasks.v3.5' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified. Confirm that the <UsingTask> declaration is correct, that the assembly and all its dependencies are available, and that the task contains a public class that implements Microsoft.Build.Framework.ITask.
```

My searches lead me to the conclusion that I must buy the Premier Edition of InstallShield to take profit of ISCmdBuild. But I can't afford it, and I think there might be another solution.

Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution. Use the command `devenv.exe` instead of `MSBuild.exe`. It will be similar to launching Visual Studio and clicking the Build button. That's all!

```
devenv.exe MySolution.sln /build Release
```

Answer (score 5):

Using Fusion logging the MSBuild checks for the DLL here: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework/v4.0.30319/Microsoft.Build.Tasks.v3.5.DLL.

I copied 
c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.5\Microsoft.Build.Tasks.v3.5.dll 
to
c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Build.Tasks.v3.5.dll

And the error is gone.

Alternatively open your *.isproj file and change from "3.5" to "4.0" on top on the tag:

```
<Project ToolsVersion="3.5"...> --> <Project ToolsVersion="4.0" ...>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I need the admin privileges to copy a file in this directory. And I don't have them...

Comment: Then try changing from 3.5 to 4.0 in the InstallShield setup file: <Project ToolsVersion="3.5" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">

Comment: I've tried following value forToolsVersion {"4", "4.0", "4.5", "4.0.30319"}. None of them work.

Comment: Worked for me. I removed the DLL and changed that value in the isproj file, checking in and it built with no 3.5 reference error.

Comment: It's weird... I don't know what to say.

Comment: Edited the isproj file manually one more time to "<Project ToolsVersion="3.5" ...". Again I get the error: "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\InstallShield\2013Limited\InstallShield.targets (21): The "Microsoft.Build.Tasks.AssignProjectConfiguration" task could not be loaded from the assembly Microsoft.Build.Tasks.v3.5.".

Comment: Then edited it back to "<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" ..." again. And it builds. Can you doublecheck that you actually have the changes in the isproj file? And of course see that you have .Net 4.0 or newer installed on the build server. I currently have 4.5.1 installed on the server.

Comment: I tried again, but still the same error: C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\InstallShield\2013Limited\InstallShield.targets(108,3): error MSB4062: The "InstallShield.Tasks.InstallShield" task could not be loaded from the assembly C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\InstallShield\2013Limited\InstallShield.Tasks.dll. Could not load file or assembly 'file:///C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\InstallShield\2013Limited\InstallShield.Tasks.dll' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format. Confirm that the <UsingTask> declaration is correct, that the assembly and...

Comment: ...all its dependencies are available, and that the task contains a public class that implements Microsoft.Build.Framework.ITask. An of course I have .NET 4.0 installed with VS2012. it's 4.5.50709 in HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP\v4\Full\Version

Comment: "An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format" - Sounds like the problem might be 32 vs 64 bit issue. Did you try the MSBuild Platform X86 value as the other response has suggested?

Comment: You have. Saw the response below. Try running the 64 version of the msbuild?

Answer (score 3):

Another solution is to force MSBuild to use the x86 platform. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/1074699/870604

If you're building from a TFS build, this can be configured from the [build options](http://geekswithblogs.net/jehan/archive/2011/01/15/building-installshield-based-installers-using-team-build-2010.aspx):

[image]

Comment: I have no TFS, so I've tried your first solution. Unfortunately, MSBuild says that "The specified solution configuration Release|x86" is invalid.