# Compiler out of heap space and MSBuild 32 bit

Tags: c++, visual-studio, compiler-errors

I'm trying to compile the library [OpenGV](https://laurentkneip.github.io/opengv/index.html) and I get the error MSVC C1060 "compiler out of heap space".

I tried to go change to x64 architecture by adding

```
<PreferredToolArchitecture>x64</PreferredToolArchitecture>
<PlatformTarget>x64</PlatformTarget>
```

to the .vxcproj file, without success. I notice however that in the resource manager, MSBuild 32 bit is still being used. Could this be the problem, and if so, how can I change the build tool (i.e. the MSbuild version), through, say, GitBash?

Comment: After adding those lines to .vcxproj file, did you restart Visual Studio?

Comment: Why are you hand-editing your project file?

Comment: Have you checked the 9 tips on MS' page? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/compiler-errors-1/fatal-error-c1060?view=msvc-170

Comment: @kiner_shah
I'm doing everything from command line, so that VS doesn't use too much memory in background

Comment: @PaulSanders I was following suggestions on how to change to x64

Answer (score 3):

If you're compiling the project through the Visual Studio IDE, the Visual Studio IDE silently uses a 32-bit compiler. To change this behavior, use the command:

```sh
msbuild {solution-name}.sln /property:Configuration=Release"
```

To find the path to the `msbuild` command on your system, use the command below:

```sh
where msbuild
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Current\Bin\MSBuild.exe
```

If the `where msbuild` command does not return a path like `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Current\Bin\MSBuild.exe`, but your system has `msbuild` installed, go to the system variables and add the `MSBuild.exe` path to the *system path* in the file structure where Microsoft Visual Studio is installed. Remove other `msbuild` path variable from system variables (like `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\MSBuild.exe`). Otherwise, this change may not work.

In another graphics library ([solution](https://github.com/uoip/g2opy/issues/29), [issue](https://github.com/uoip/g2opy/issues/25)) it is reported how to solve a similar problem and its solution is reported as solved as above.

When installing OpenGV under Window it is stated in the documentation that the `msbuild` configuration should be changed as follows:

```sh
msbuild opengv.sln /p:Configuration=Release
```

In addition, if the `cmake` build tool will be used in the project, the following declaration should be made using the `-G` option to compile for x64 target machine:

```sh
  cmake -G "Visual Studio 16 2019" -A x64   ../
# cmake -G "Visual Studio 16 2019" -A Win32 ../
# cmake -G "Visual Studio 16 2019" -A ARM   ../
# cmake -G "Visual Studio 16 2019" -A ARM64 ../
```

Comment: So changing Configuration to Release will automatically switch to 64-bit compiler?

Comment: How to solve a similar problem in another graphics library has been reported and the solution has been shared: [g2opy](https://github.com/uoip/g2opy/issues/29), [issue](https://github.com/uoip/g2opy/issues/25).

Comment: [The OpenGV Documentation](https://laurentkneip.github.io/opengv/page_installation.html) already explains how CMAKE should be configured: `msbuild opengv.sln /p:Configuration=Release`.

Comment: Yes, it does indeed. Can you include these points in your answer by editing them?

Comment: I edited the post. Hope it will be useful for the community.

Comment: @SercanSebetçi Did you mean c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\amd64\MSBuild.exe ?

(the amd64 part)

Comment: I tried it at my local. My way is the way I share.

Comment: [What's New in MSBuild 16.0 - Changed Path](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/whats-new-msbuild-16-0?view=vs-2022#:~:text=For%20example%2C%20the%20path%20to,module%20to%20locate%20MSBuild%3A%20vssetup.)

Comment: After trying to build again, before implementing your suggestions, I noticed that C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Current\Bin\MSBuild.exe is already being used (and it is 32 bit). I had already specified "-A x64" in the CMake build tool.

Comment: The fact that the directory where MsBuild.exe is located is in the x86 file structure does not mean that it is running in 32-bit mode.

Comment: The following command is used to force MSBuild to run in 32-bit mod mode: `msbuild {solution-name}.sln /t:build /p:Configuration=Release;Platform=x86`

I recommend you to read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1074654/how-do-i-force-msbuild-to-compile-for-32-bit-mode) as well.

Comment: @SercanSebetçi However, the process that is running is named "MSBuild.exe (32 bit)". To the post you linked: I have already tried to follow their tips but MSBuild is no matter what I do still executed in the 32 bit version.
What is best in this case is to try to run a 64 bit version of it, right?

Comment: The reason for this error is (most likely) stated to be the 32-bit compiler run of msbuild in the background, even if you set the target architecture to 64-bit to improve debugging performance. I shared one of the ways to change this behavior in the post.

Comment: @SercanSebetçi Thanks again, I'll try a build overnight an report the results.

Comment: @SercanSebetçi I tried implementing your suggestion (all the time building from command line, no IDE open), MSBuild 32 bit was still being used. I even changed to ...MSBuild\15.0\Bin\amd64\MSBuild.exe, and still it didn't work

Comment: (though, when using the amd64 folder, MSBuild wasn't showing the text "32 Bit" anymore)

Comment: Have you tried the `msbuild` tool with root directory **"Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community"**?

Comment: If it calls msbuild without specifying a path from the command line, you may be running a different msbuild file. You can see [this link](https://pureinfotech.com/list-environment-variables-windows-10/) to view windows environmental variables, and [this link](https://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm) to change environmental variables.